# Tails/Tor not connecting to Network using multiple OBSF 3 OR 4 bridges

Tags: tails, bridge, proxy, obfs4

I have a tails install running off USB running on a laptop with Parrot linux installed. Tor connects fine without bridges. I used welcome screen to set up bridge list and cannot connect. Bridges have been copied from Tor DB, and have tried 4 x OBFS3, then 4 x OBFS4 servers, then up to 16 OBFS4 server entries (1 per line as per instructions). I have duplicated the same 16 server list in a windows TOR set up accessing the same wireless network at around the same time and connection is ok. Why is it not working in Tails/tor only?
Copied below is portions of the log file with external server addresses "xxx" out:

```
02/16/2017 18:29:19.400 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
02/16/2017 18:29:20.200 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
02/16/2017 18:29:21.200 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
02/16/2017 18:29:22.300 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
02/16/2017 18:29:23.300 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 

02/16/2017 18:30:42.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
02/16/2017 18:30:42.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 

02/16/2017 18:30:42.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
02/16/2017 18:30:42.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061 
02/16/2017 18:30:42.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9062 
02/16/2017 18:30:42.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
02/16/2017 18:30:42.300 [NOTICE] Opening DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
02/16/2017 18:30:42.300 [NOTICE] Opening Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
02/16/2017 18:30:42.300 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "/etc/tor/torrc.orig.1" 
02/16/2017 18:30:42.800 [NOTICE] New control connection opened from 127.0.0.1. 
02/16/2017 18:30:44.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
02/16/2017 18:30:44.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
02/16/2017 18:31:21.100 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 178.62.xxx.xx:9443 ("general SOCKS server failure") 
02/16/2017 18:31:22.200 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 194.132.xxx.xxx:53418 ("general SOCKS server failure") 

02/16/2017 18:35:03.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Transparent pf/netfilter listener on 127.0.0.1:9040 
02/16/2017 18:35:03.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured DNS listener on 127.0.0.1:5353 
02/16/2017 18:35:03.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050 
02/16/2017 18:35:03.400 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9061
```

Comment: How does the rest of the network seem from Tails? If you use the Unsafe Browser can you browse the internet okay? Does the system log provide you any insight into possible network errors? (To get system logs, launch the Whisperback tool)

Answer (score 0):

Set the time zone to London and change time to London time. You can update the time first when you connect to the wireless internet (not yet configuring tor), once that is done you can connect without any problem. If there are problems, try -1 hour or +1 hour to account for daylight savings depending on your area. Mine was -1 and worked well.

You can also edit the `iat-mode=0` to `iat-mode=1` or `iat-mode=2`.

Good luck.

Comment: N.B. you shouldn't really edit `iat-mode`, it isn't helpful to use it if the server isn't configured to also.